# How to store multiple values at an index in a Stack?

Tags: java, stack

I'm trying to upadte my validity checker for my Sudoku solver, but I'm not really sure how to use `Stacks` in the way that I want. I already know how the basics when it comes to `Stacks`, but I'm trying to store multiple values at one index.

My Sudoku board is stored in a 3D array, so in my stack I need to store the value, sub-square where the value was found, row it was found in and column it was found in.

So suppose that my array was this:

```
 int[][][] solved = {{{5,3,4},{6,7,2},{1,9,8}}, //Let's say I want to check if 5 is in the right position.
                    {{6,7,8},{1,9,5},{3,4,2}},
                    {{9,1,2},{3,4,8},{5,6,7}},
                    {{8,5,9},{4,2,6},{7,1,3}},
                    {{7,6,1},{8,5,3},{9,2,4}},
                    {{4,2,3},{7,9,1},{8,5,6}},
                    {{9,6,1},{2,8,7},{3,4,5}},
                    {{5,3,7},{4,1,9},{2,8,6}},
                    {{2,8,4},{6,3,5},{1,7,9}}};
```

The information would be [5,0,0,0].

I already have a working checker but now I need to know how to store multiple values at a single index in a `Stack`. This way if it is in the wrong position, I can just pop it off and try a different number.

Any insight will be appreciated!

Comment: Either use an int array or create a custom class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object that encapsulates the group of values. The class should mark the fields `private` and provide getters and setters, but I've left it out for brevity.
I also don't know the types for the data, I'm assuming `int`.

```
public class Move 
{
    public int value;
    public int row;
    public int subSquare;
}
```

Then you will have `Stack<Move>`

Then you can add `Move`s to the stack:

```
Stack<Move> stack = ...
Move move = new Move();
move.value = 1;
move.row = 2;
move.subSquare = 3;
stack.push(move);
```

Comment: Editing my grammer, okay. Editing the code to move the open brace to be on the same line? Blasphemy